# Multithreading not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to test a couple of things with regards to iterators being shared across multiple threads. I wrote a very simple (and quite stupid) program which is supposed to iterate through the same map intwo different threads. Here's the code:

```
    final Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    final Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i< 1000 ; i++){
        m.put(r.nextInt(10000), r.nextInt(10000));
    }
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Iterator<Integer> it = m.keySet().iterator();
            it.next();
            for(Integer i : m.keySet()){
                System.out.println("T1  " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(100));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Iterator<Integer> it = m.keySet().iterator();
            it.next();
            for(Integer i : m.keySet()){
                System.out.println("T2  " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(100));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    });

    t1.run();
    t2.run();
```

Now, when I run this I was expecting to either get exception of concurrent modification of some sort, or mixture of both "T1 " and "T2 " messages in the console. What happens is my program outputs ALL values from map for thread 1 and THEN progresses to thread 2. Why is this serializable behaviour the case here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `t1.start()` and `t2.start()` rather than `run`.

Calling `run` will simply execute the code from your `run` method.
`start` is what launches a new thread.

Comment: Wow... really sorry for such a stupid question. Thanks for a very prompt reply.

Comment: No problem. I only noticed it so quickly because I've made the same mistake several times in the past. I think the API for thread is a bit poorly designed in this respect - it's too easy to make this mistake.

Comment: @Tim I totally agree with that. And Bober02, I think pretty much everyone's made that mistake at some point, so don't sweat it. It's the "there/they're/their" of `Thread`. :)

Comment: The reason for this is because you override `run()`, so unless Sun did some hardcoding for Thread, you'll have to call a native method (`start()`).

Comment: Yes, but why does `Thread` need to implement `Runnable`? The style where `Thread` _has-a_ `Runnable` is the good part of the API, the fact that `Thread` _is-a_ `Runnable` is bad. On balance, I think allowing people to inherit from thread and override `run` is a bad design decision - it would have been better to only have the _has-a_ style of usage for `Thread`.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the operation in a single thread (main thread) because you are executing t.run() instead of t.start().

Having said that, note that using two thread does not always result in interleaved execution; often doing the operations sequentially is more efficient, and thus the JVM schedules the actual operation sequentially.

Further, concurrent modification detection of the standard hash map is best effort and is not a guaranteed mechanism.